# ¿Cómo pedir únicamente la contraseña si la ingresada anteriormente es incorrecta?

Tags: java, login

Hice este login con los consejos que me dieron en mi pregunta pasada pero ahora me surgió otra duda, si al iniciar sesión, cuando solicite la contraseña y se ingrese una incorrecta vuelva a solicitar únicamente la contraseña, no todo el inicio de sesión de nuevo. ¿Alguna idea?

```
public static void contra() {
    int numUsers;//Número de usuarios a registrar
    //Contadores
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    String passw[]= new String[256];//Contenedor de contraseñas
    String users[]= new String[256];//Contenedor de nombres de usuario
    //Variables temporales
    String Tuser=new String();
    String Tpass=new String();
    //Almacén del índice
    int getPos=0;

    //Registro de usuarios
    System.out.println("---REGISTRO DE USUARIOS---\n Cuántos usuarios deseas registrar?");
    numUsers=s.nextInt();
    for(i=1;i<=numUsers;i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del usuario "+i);
        users[i]=s.next();
        System.out.println("Ingresa la contraseña del usuario "+users[i]);
        passw[i]=s.next();
        System.out.println("***USUARIO REGISTRADO CON ÉXITO***\n");
    }

    //Validación de usuario
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {//Se dan 5 intentos, de no ser así el programa rebota y necesita que se ejucte de nuevo
        System.out.println("---INICIO DE SESIÓN---\n Ingresa un usuario: ");
        Tuser=s.next();//Se usa una variable temporal para poder hacer la comparación
        for(j=1;j<users.length;j++) {//Se recorre el array hasta encontrar coincidencias
            if(Tuser.equals(users[j])) {
                getPos=j;//Si hay una coincidencia guarda la posición ya que el usuario 1 tiene la contraseña con el mismo índice
                System.out.println("Ingresa la contraseña del usuario "+Tuser);
                Tpass=s.next();//Se usa una variable temporal para poder hacer la comparación
                if(Tpass.equals(passw[getPos])) {//Evalua si la contraseña ingresa coincide con la del array en el índice ya obtenido
                    System.out.println("***ACCESO CONCEDIDO***\n");
                    callAll();//Ejecuta el resto del programa
                    System.out.println("***CERRANDO SESIÓN***\n");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("***ERROR: NO COINCIDE LA CONTRASEÑA***\n");
                    break;
                }
                break;//Una vez terminado se sale del for
            }//
            else
                continue;//Si no se cumple la condición se reinica el ciclo y se agrega un uno al contador de intentos
        }//

    }
}
```

Comment: Una recomendación muy importante cuando se desarrollen componentes de ingreso a sistemas es “Evitar evidenciar qué componentes de las credenciales son los que se ingresaron mal”. Esto es vital para evitar ataques por fuerza bruta. Es decir, deberías decirle al usuario que sus “CREDECIALES” están mal, pero no especificarle que fue la contraseña o el usuario lo que ingresó mal.

De otra forma, podría intentar cientos de veces con el mismo usuario y diferentes contraseñas… y ya el mismo sistema me va a ayudar a “romper” su propia seguridad.

Comment: No lo había visto de esa forma, generalmente lo hago como el amigo SrCatsup, gracias por la recomendación.

Answer (score 1):

Yo pondria el mensaje de "ingreso de contraseña" y su posterior validacion dentro de un ciclo *DO WHILE*.

Entonces te queda:

- Mientras el usuario me siga ingresando una contraseña incorrecta, le sigo pidiendo la contraseña.

**Aca te hice un ejemplo basico de lo que dije:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String contrasenia;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
        System.out.println("ingrese la contraseña");
        contrasenia = scan.next();
        System.out.println(contrasenia);
    }while(!contrasenia.equals("asdf"));

    System.out.println("entrando al sistema...");
}
```

PD: Despues a esto, con flags booleanos podes controlar los intentos fallidos, etc...